# Error C2512 'DerivedClass' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, class, pointers, derived

I am having an issue with this error, and adding a default constructor does not fix it. compiling without default constructors produces the error, compiling with default constructors produces the error. I've been searching online for hours but found nothing. Here's a quick example of my code (The actual code is rather long):

```
//Header.h
using namespace std;

class BaseClass;
class DerivedClass;

BaseClass *MyClass = new DerivedClass;

class BaseClass
{
    virtual void myFunction()
    {
        cout << "Base Class";
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    void myFunction()
    {
        cout << "Derived Class";
    }
};

//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h" //I believe this gives Header.h access to iostream 
                    //I believe it cause it works

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

The error is in Header.h, Main is only there to give Header.h access to iostream.
As I said I've look for HOURS. And haven't found any ways to fix the error:
Error C2512: 'DerivedClass' : no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: `new DerivedClass` requires the `DerivedClass` definition. You only have a forward declaration. You also need to `#include <iostream>` in `Header.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need this in header file?

```
Baseclass *MyClass = new DerivedClass;
```

Clearly compiler is looking for definition of `derived` class and not found till this line executes.

Move it after implementation of `derived` class or in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Baseclass *MyClass = new DerivedClass;
```

should come after the definition of the classes, i.e. end of file

P.S. your comment in the code (about giving access to iostream) is correct. But consider it is not good practice. Header files should compile with no requisites on different inclusions.

instantiating the `MyClass` object within the .h is no good practic either.

Comment: moving it around causes a whole lot more errors. putting BaseClass *MyClass = new DerivedClass in global scope of main gives me 8 errors. The error c2512 is still there, and it adds Error C2605: 'MyClass' : undefined identifier aswell as Error C2541: 'delete' : cannot delete object that are not pointers when I try to delete MyClass to assign another derived class to it

Comment: also, change Baseclass into BaseClass , I didn't notice it before

Comment: here's a better example of what I'm doing in VS2010 http://ideone.com/ogt3cu this one has errors. If it comes to it I might have to end up copy pasting my whole header file -_-"

Answer (score 0):

You program is totally invalid.

You allocate memory for class DerivedClass but it is not defined yet.

```
Baseclass *MyClass = new DerivedClass;
```

You use standard output stream

```
cout << "Base Class";
```

but it is not declared yet because there is no the corresponding header where the stream is declared.

The definition of function myFunction has no sense because it has private access control and may not be called outside methods of the class itself but there is no such a method.

The correct code could look the following way

```
//Header.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void myFunction() const
    {
        cout << "Base Class";
    }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    void myFunction() const
    {
        cout << "Derived Class";
    }
};

//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h" //I believe this gives Header.h access to iostream 
                    //I believe it cause it works

using namespace std;

Baseclass *MyClass = new DerivedClass;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

Comment: This is a better example of what I am trying to do, I'm about ready to give up and use ifs http://ideone.com/ogt3cu